# How to pass JSON file to BQ using Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a JSON file in bucket and I am trying to pass it to BQ using DAG but getting an error. Also I am truncating the table whenever new JSON File will upload in BQ.

My JSON File looks like this :-

```
{"ID":"4238382","Title":"El clon Cap\u00edtulo 3","Description":"Said y Ali llegan a un acuerdo. Leonidas sale con Yvete y Diogo. Edvaldo no quiere hacerse los ex\u00e1menes. Jade se reh\u00fasa a usar velo. Lucas se disculpa con Ali. Albieri dice que Ali fue duro con Jade, Ali lo acusa de querer experimentar con humanos.","Program":"El Clon","Season":"1","Episode":"3","Source":"GLOBO TV INTERNACIONAL","Category":"Drama","Syndicator":"CSv2","[CSv2] external_id":"ELCL100002002","[CSv2] pub_win_US_begin":"1661842800","[CSv2] pub_win_US_end":"1754625600","[CSv2] language":"es","[CSv2] title":"El clon Cap\u00edtulo 3","[CSv2] descriptive_title":"Acuerdo de matrimonio","[CSv2] description":"Said y Ali llegan a un acuerdo. Leonidas sale con Yvete y Diogo. Edvaldo no quiere hacerse los ex\u00e1menes. Jade se reh\u00fasa a usar velo. Lucas se disculpa con Ali. Albieri dice que Ali fue duro con Jade, Ali lo acusa de querer experimentar con humanos.","[CSv2] supplier":"GLOBO TV INTERNACIONAL","[CSv2] categories":"Drama","[CSv2] rating":"TV-14","[CSv2] subratings":"D","[CSv2] program_type":"NOVELA","[CSv2] entity":"","[CSv2] exception_countries":"US ,\tUM ,PR ,\tMX ,\tAR ,\tCL ,\tCO ,\tPE ,\tEC ,\tCR ,\tSV ,\tHN ,\tBO ,\tPA ,\tDO ,\tNI ,\tPY ,\tVE ,\tUY ,\tGT","[CSv2] episode_type":"","TMS ID":null,"external_id":"ELCL100002002","Content Type":"Entertainment","Release Year":"2001","sports_event_ID":""}
```

I have created a table in BQ with all JSON Keys as column :-
[image: BQ Table]

My DAG Code :-

```
def source_exists(ti):
    source_folder = list_files_in_bucket(mcp_bucket, mcp_source_folder)
    source_files = []
    for file in source_folder:
        if file.endswith(".json"):
            source_files.append(file)
    if len(source_files) == 0:
        ti.xcom_push(key="json_error_file", value=True)
        raise AirflowException("Source files dont exist")
    ti.xcom_push(key="json_error_file", value=False)

with DAG(
    dag_id=dag_id,
    #schedule_interval=schedule_mcp,
    default_args=default_dag_args,
) as dag:
    source_folder = list_files_in_bucket(mcp_bucket, mcp_source_folder)
    source_files = []
    for file in source_folder:
        if file.endswith(".json"):
            source_files.append(file)

 mcp_ingestion_to_bq = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id="mcp_ingestion_to_bq",
        retries=0,
        dag=dag,
        bucket=mcp_bucket,
        source_objects=f"{mcp_source_folder}*.json",
        source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
        #skip_leading_rows=16,
        destination_project_dataset_table=destination_bq_table,
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        create_disposition="CREATE_NEVER",
        
        autodetect="False"
    )
```

I am getting error :-

```
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py", line 135, in result
    raise self._exception
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: gs://st-vix-ott-dev-data-usea1-akta/mcp-tr-mapping/datalatetest1.json
[2022-08-31 04:05:34,411] {taskinstance.py:1511} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=test_mcp_ingestion, task_id=mcp_ingestion_to_bq, execution_date=20220831T040508, start_date=20220831T040530, end_date=20220831T040534
[2022-08-31 04:05:34,592] {local_task_job.py:151} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-08-31 04:05:34,687] {local_task_job.py:261} INFO - 1 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Comment: It might be because the keys in your JSON contain illegal characters like brackets `[]`? See [column naming](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names). It is better if you can also post the BQ logs containing the error.

Comment: @RiccoD :  My JSON file contains many fields like [CSv2] external_id with which I can't create a table in BQ but the JSON File is creating these names only. So is this possible that I can create a table with CSv2_external_id as field and create a plugin file where I can map this field with original field name([CSv2] external_id). If yes, Please let me know how I can do it and use this plugin file in my DAG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is due to params passed to `GCSToBigQueryOperator`.

The `autodetect` is passed as False, and you don't passed `schema_fields` or `schema_object` param.

Either you specify `autodetect` as True, otherwise you have to pass the table schema (Json) with `schema_fields` or `schema_object`.

Example with autodetect with True :

```py
def source_exists(ti):
    source_folder = list_files_in_bucket(mcp_bucket, mcp_source_folder)
    source_files = []
    for file in source_folder:
        if file.endswith(".json"):
            source_files.append(file)
    if len(source_files) == 0:
        ti.xcom_push(key="json_error_file", value=True)
        raise AirflowException("Source files dont exist")
    ti.xcom_push(key="json_error_file", value=False)

with DAG(
    dag_id=dag_id,
    #schedule_interval=schedule_mcp,
    default_args=default_dag_args,
) as dag:
    source_folder = list_files_in_bucket(mcp_bucket, mcp_source_folder)
    source_files = []
    for file in source_folder:
        if file.endswith(".json"):
            source_files.append(file)

 mcp_ingestion_to_bq = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id="mcp_ingestion_to_bq",
        retries=0,
        dag=dag,
        bucket=mcp_bucket,
        source_objects=f"{mcp_source_folder}*.json",
        source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
        #skip_leading_rows=16,
        destination_project_dataset_table=destination_bq_table,
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        create_disposition="CREATE_NEVER",
        autodetect=True
    )
```

Example with schema_fields and autodetect as False :

```py
def source_exists(ti):
    source_folder = list_files_in_bucket(mcp_bucket, mcp_source_folder)
    source_files = []
    for file in source_folder:
        if file.endswith(".json"):
            source_files.append(file)
    if len(source_files) == 0:
        ti.xcom_push(key="json_error_file", value=True)
        raise AirflowException("Source files dont exist")
    ti.xcom_push(key="json_error_file", value=False)

with DAG(
    dag_id=dag_id,
    #schedule_interval=schedule_mcp,
    default_args=default_dag_args,
) as dag:
    source_folder = list_files_in_bucket(mcp_bucket, mcp_source_folder)
    source_files = []
    for file in source_folder:
        if file.endswith(".json"):
            source_files.append(file)
 
 # Replace by your schema fields. You can also use a Json file and use Python json.loads(jsonFile).
 schema_fields=[
                 {'name': 'Col1', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
                 {'name': 'Col2', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}
             ]

 mcp_ingestion_to_bq = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id="mcp_ingestion_to_bq",
        retries=0,
        dag=dag,
        bucket=mcp_bucket,
        source_objects=f"{mcp_source_folder}*.json",
        source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
        #skip_leading_rows=16,
        destination_project_dataset_table=destination_bq_table,
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        create_disposition="CREATE_NEVER",
        autodetect=False,
        schema_fields=schema_fields
    )
```

Comment: My JSON file contains many fields like [CSv2] external_id with which I can't create a table in BQ but the JSON File is creating these names only. So is this possible that I can create a table with CSv2_external_id as field and create a plugin file where I can map this field with original field name([CSv2] external_id). If yes, Please let me know how I can do it and use this plugin file in my DAG  @Mazlum Tosun